# Regex to determine there are no any special symbols, characters or digits

Tags: regex, azure-synapse

I have a requirement to determine whether an expression is empty. I have to consider there are no any characters, no digits or no other symbols.

Comment: So you need to check that a string is only white-space?

Comment: but there may be not white spaces....just empty string

Comment: `^$` matches an empty string

Comment: Why use a regexp? Why not just `var == ''`?

Comment: but it not checks numbers...

Comment: You said there can't be numbers.

Comment: Yes not numbers or characters

Comment: Can you add some valid and invalid input samples in question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This pattern matches empty strings and strings containing only white spaces:

```
^\s*$
```

This one only accepts empty strings:

```
^$
```

However in this case, you probably don't need regexes, as [@Barmar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1491895/barmar) pointed out, it should be easier to check with an equality operator:

```
a == "" // syntax depends on the language you're using
```

This will check that the variable `a` is an empty string. Containing nothing.

Comment: He said there shouldn't be whitespace.

Comment: He said that there may be no white spaces. Although it's not perfectly clear, I give you that :)

Comment: @Malintha what are trying to match? Did you want to match line breaks? `^[\n\r\t\f]+$`

Comment: No I am Apache Synapse language, There I have only checking option is regex, I want to check whether a property value is empty, zero length , any regex so far do not fit

Comment: `^$` does exactly that.

Answer (score 1):

As @fejese mentioned `^$` matches empty string but it also matches empty line so it should be the answer.